# Interface parameter function not found

Tags: java, interface, parameters

I have the following code:

```
public class Utils{
    public static void closeQuietly(Closeable c){
         try{c.close();} catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
         Closeable cl = new Socket();
         closeQuietly(cl);
    }
}
```

This seems straightforward, but for some reason I get the following compiler error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
closeQuietly(cl);
^
symbol:   method closeQuietly(Closeable)
location: class Utils
```

and I don't understand why.

Comment: Perhaps `c.close;` is confusing things. try `c.close();`

Comment: @John3136: You have corrected an error (1+), but it won't cause the compile error he's showing I don't think.

Comment: Yeah, it is c.close(). I just missed it in the copy-pasting. I'll update the question.

Comment: On my system, after fixing the parentheses of close(), the class compiles correctly.

Comment: Yep, it's a non-question I think.

Comment: Don't know about the compiler error you're getting, but be careful--`Socket` only implements `Closeable` in Java 7+.

Comment: @MarkPeters you are right, if OP's code is not in Java 7 he needs to add casting  `Closeable cl = (Closeable)new Socket();` But I still don't understand how OP gets that error. strange =)

Comment: @BlueBullet: Wouldn't that be a CCE at runtime then?

Comment: @BheshGurung Yes, it would. What I mean is that OP's code is in Java 7. How he gets this error?

Comment: @MarkPeters I am using Java 7. Thats why the declaration doesn't cause a compilation/runtime error. I guess this means that Im not crazy though and what I have should work. Probably something wrong with my environment.

Comment: @Dgrin91: Clean and rebuild should be your first approach.  Have you tried compiling *exactly* what you've shown above, or are you distilling it from your actual code, and haven't actually tried compiling the above?  i.e. in your project, the main method is actually in the same class?

Comment: @MarkPeters Yeah, I tried that beforehand. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in ideone.com and it compiles just fine.

From the compile error message, it is obviously it cannot find `closeQuietly(Closeable)`, and the "arrow" is pointing at the method name, that is very likely that no method with such name exists.  Please check again if you have any typo in your actual code.